# Find earliest date within daterange

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following market data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'day': [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,30,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26,27,30]})

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data)

data['spot'] = [77.3438,78.192,78.1044,78.4357,78.0285,77.3507,76.78,77.13,77.0417,77.6525,78.0906,77.91,77.6602,77.3568,76.7243,76.5872,76.1374,76.4435,77.2906,79.2239,78.8993,79.5305,80.5313,79.3615,77.0156,77.4226,76.288,76.5648,77.1171,77.3568,77.374,76.1758,76.2325,76.0401,76.0529,76.1992,76.1648,75.474,75.551,75.7018,75.8639,76.3944]

data = data.set_index('date')
```

I'm trying to find the spot value for the first day of the month in the date column. I can find the first business day with below:

```
def get_month_beg(d):
    month_beg = (d.index + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True)) 
    return month_beg

data['month_beg'] =  get_month_beg(data)
```

However, due to data issues, sometimes the earliest date from my data does not match up with the first business day of the month.

We'll call the earliest spot value of each month the "strike", which is what I'm trying to find. So for October, the spot value would be 77.3438 (10/1/21) and in Nov it would be 80.5313 (which is on 11/2/21 NOT 11/1/21).

I tried below, which only works if my data's earliest date matches up with the first business date of the month (eg it works in Oct, but not in Nov)

```
 data['strike'] = data.month_beg.map(data.spot)
```

As you can see, I get NaN in Nov because the first business day in my data is 11/2 (spot rate 80.5313) not 11/1. Does anyone know how to find the earliest date within a date range (in this case the earliest date of each month)?

I was hoping the final df would like like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'day': [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,30,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26,27,30]})

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data)

data['spot'] = [77.3438,78.192,78.1044,78.4357,78.0285,77.3507,76.78,77.13,77.0417,77.6525,78.0906,77.91,77.6602,77.3568,76.7243,76.5872,76.1374,76.4435,77.2906,79.2239,78.8993,79.5305,80.5313,79.3615,77.0156,77.4226,76.288,76.5648,77.1171,77.3568,77.374,76.1758,76.2325,76.0401,76.0529,76.1992,76.1648,75.474,75.551,75.7018,75.8639,76.3944]

data['strike'] = [77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,77.3438,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313,80.5313]

data = data.set_index('date')
```

Answer (score 1):

I Believe, We can get the first() for every year and month combination and later on join that with main data.

```
data2=data.groupby(['year','month']).first().reset_index()
#join data 2 with data based on month and year later on

   year  month  day     spot
0  2020     10    1  77.3438
1  2020     11    2  80.5313
```

Based on the question, What i have understood is that we need to take every month's first day and respective 'SPOT' column value.

Correct me if i have understood it wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to add the "strike" column so that the dataframe remains the same (but with the added column)? So the final dataframe has all the dates, spot values, and strike column (which would be 77.3438 for every date in Oct and 80.5313 for every date in Nov)? I added how I was hoping the final df would like like in the question at the end.

Comment: @HDBrew

data['strike']=data.groupby(['year','month'])['spot'].transform('first')

We can try this, Should work in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

## Strike = Spot value from first day of each month

To do this, we need to do the following:

- Step 1. Get the Year/Month value from the Date column. Alternate, we
  can use `Year` and `Month` columns you already have in the DataFrame.
- Step 2: We need to groupby Year and Month. That will give all the
  records by Year+Month. From this, we need to get the first record
  (which will be the earliest date of the month). The earliest date can
  either be 1st or 2nd or 3rd of the month depending on the data in the
  column.
- Step 3: By using transform in Groupby, pandas will send back the
  results to match the dataframe length. So for each record, it will
  send the same result. In this example, we have only 2 months (Oct &
  Nov). However, we have 42 rows. Transform will send us back 42 rows.
  The code: groupby('[year','month'])['date'].transform('first') will give
  first day of month.

Use This:

```
data['dy'] = data.groupby(['year','month'])['date'].transform('first')
```

or:

```
data['dx'] = data.date.dt.to_period('M') #to get yyyy-mm value
```

- Step 4: Using transform, we can also get the Spot value. This can be
  assigned to Strike giving us the desired result. Instead of getting
  first day of the month, we can change it to return Spot value.
  The code will be: groupby('date')['spot'].transform('first')

Use this:

```
data['strike'] = data.groupby(['year','month'])['spot'].transform('first')
```

or

```
data['strike'] = data.groupby('dx')['spot'].transform('first')
```

**Putting all this together**

The full code to get Strike Price using Spot Price from first day of month

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'day': [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,30,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26,27,30]})

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data)

data['spot'] = [77.3438,78.192,78.1044,78.4357,78.0285,77.3507,76.78,77.13,77.0417,77.6525,78.0906,77.91,77.6602,77.3568,76.7243,76.5872,76.1374,76.4435,77.2906,79.2239,78.8993,79.5305,80.5313,79.3615,77.0156,77.4226,76.288,76.5648,77.1171,77.3568,77.374,76.1758,76.2325,76.0401,76.0529,76.1992,76.1648,75.474,75.551,75.7018,75.8639,76.3944]

#Pick the first day of month Spot price as the Strike price
data['strike'] = data.groupby(['year','month'])['spot'].transform('first')

#This will give you the first row of each month
print (data)
```

The output of this will be:

```
    year  month  day       date     spot   strike
0   2020     10    1 2020-10-01  77.3438  77.3438
1   2020     10    2 2020-10-02  78.1920  77.3438
2   2020     10    5 2020-10-05  78.1044  77.3438
3   2020     10    6 2020-10-06  78.4357  77.3438
4   2020     10    7 2020-10-07  78.0285  77.3438
5   2020     10    8 2020-10-08  77.3507  77.3438
6   2020     10    9 2020-10-09  76.7800  77.3438
7   2020     10   12 2020-10-12  77.1300  77.3438
8   2020     10   13 2020-10-13  77.0417  77.3438
9   2020     10   14 2020-10-14  77.6525  77.3438
10  2020     10   15 2020-10-15  78.0906  77.3438
11  2020     10   16 2020-10-16  77.9100  77.3438
12  2020     10   19 2020-10-19  77.6602  77.3438
13  2020     10   20 2020-10-20  77.3568  77.3438
14  2020     10   21 2020-10-21  76.7243  77.3438
15  2020     10   22 2020-10-22  76.5872  77.3438
16  2020     10   23 2020-10-23  76.1374  77.3438
17  2020     10   26 2020-10-26  76.4435  77.3438
18  2020     10   27 2020-10-27  77.2906  77.3438
19  2020     10   28 2020-10-28  79.2239  77.3438
20  2020     10   29 2020-10-29  78.8993  77.3438
21  2020     10   30 2020-10-30  79.5305  77.3438
22  2020     11    2 2020-11-02  80.5313  80.5313
23  2020     11    3 2020-11-03  79.3615  80.5313
24  2020     11    5 2020-11-05  77.0156  80.5313
25  2020     11    6 2020-11-06  77.4226  80.5313
26  2020     11    9 2020-11-09  76.2880  80.5313
27  2020     11   10 2020-11-10  76.5648  80.5313
28  2020     11   11 2020-11-11  77.1171  80.5313
29  2020     11   12 2020-11-12  77.3568  80.5313
30  2020     11   13 2020-11-13  77.3740  80.5313
31  2020     11   16 2020-11-16  76.1758  80.5313
32  2020     11   17 2020-11-17  76.2325  80.5313
33  2020     11   18 2020-11-18  76.0401  80.5313
34  2020     11   19 2020-11-19  76.0529  80.5313
35  2020     11   20 2020-11-20  76.1992  80.5313
36  2020     11   23 2020-11-23  76.1648  80.5313
37  2020     11   24 2020-11-24  75.4740  80.5313
38  2020     11   25 2020-11-25  75.5510  80.5313
39  2020     11   26 2020-11-26  75.7018  80.5313
40  2020     11   27 2020-11-27  75.8639  80.5313
41  2020     11   30 2020-11-30  76.3944  80.5313
```

## Previous Answer to get the first day of each month (within the column data)

One way to do it is to create a dummy column to store the first day of each month. Then use drop_duplicates() and retain only the first row.

**Key assumption:**
The assumption with this logic is that we have at least 2 rows for each month. If there is only one row for a month, then it will not be part of the duplicates and you will NOT get that month's data.

That will give you the first day of each month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'day': [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,30,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26,27,30]})

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data)

data['spot'] = [77.3438,78.192,78.1044,78.4357,78.0285,77.3507,76.78,77.13,77.0417,77.6525,78.0906,77.91,77.6602,77.3568,76.7243,76.5872,76.1374,76.4435,77.2906,79.2239,78.8993,79.5305,80.5313,79.3615,77.0156,77.4226,76.288,76.5648,77.1171,77.3568,77.374,76.1758,76.2325,76.0401,76.0529,76.1992,76.1648,75.474,75.551,75.7018,75.8639,76.3944]

#create a dummy column to store the first day of the month
data['dx'] = data.date.dt.to_period('M')

#drop duplicates while retaining only the first row of each month
dx = data.drop_duplicates('dx',keep='first')

#This will give you the first row of each month
print (dx)
```

The output of this will be:

```
    year  month  day       date     spot       dx
0   2020     10    1 2020-10-01  77.3438  2020-10
22  2020     11    2 2020-11-02  80.5313  2020-11
```

If there is only one row for a given month, then you can use groupby the month and take the first record.

```
data.groupby(['dx']).first()
```

This will give you:

```
         year  month  day       date     spot
dx                                           
2020-10  2020     10    1 2020-10-01  77.3438
2020-11  2020     11    2 2020-11-02  80.5313
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the "strike" column so that the dataframe remains the same (but with the added column)? So the final dataframe has all the dates, spot values, and strike column (which would be 77.3438 for every date in Oct and 80.5313 for every date in Nov)? I added how I was hoping the final df would like like in the question at the end.

Comment: Yes it can be. Let ne add that and post

Comment: @HDBrew, see my new updated answer. Let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['strike']=data.groupby(['year','month'])['spot'].transform('first')
```

I guess this can be achieved by this without creating any other dataframe.